# Docker-compose how add volume to save logs from java app in windows/mac

Tags: docker, docker-compose

my docker compose file looks like:

```
  app:
    image: app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8080:8080
```

as far as I know docker is storing logs into virtual disc, so how can I copy logs from there and store into my host machine

In fact, I tried to add

```
volumes:
  - ./logs:/home/logs
```

but only directory logs is creating, there are no logs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you talking about the logs from the docker engine itself, or logs generated by the application running in docker?

Comment: about logs generated by the application running in docker

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that the target folder in the docker container is wrong. You specify `/home/logs` - which seems like an odd place. That would mean that the logs are stored in the home folder *of a user named 'logs'*.

Are you sure that is the path where logs are stored in the docker container?

Comment: I am not sure. How can I check it when I am using windows?